# How to make windows automatically close windows error dialogs?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I've followed the tutorial from [here](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-error-reporting-windows) but I still get these:

[image]

Any ideas how to make the program auto close?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, the tutorial you linked only show how to disable the automatic check for a solution when a process crashes and from your screenshot, it seems like it worked just fine. Setting that option doesn't stop an error message from appearing when a process crashes.